# grub menu can't be dispalyed

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, wireless, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 along aside Windows 10. While booting Ubuntu is not appearing instead its directly opening the Windows os. The grub menu is not found, its hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I can present to you a simple hack for this problem, use it if none of  the legit solutions solved your problem. I am assuming you have a UEFI boot system.

As Windows keeps changing the boot order, the hack is to trick Windows to recognize Ubuntu grub as Windows boot file i.e. *bootmgfw.efi*

> Part 1: Accessing EFI folder on Windows

Open *cmd* as administrator and mount the EFI folder to access it. Execute  the following commands one bye one. Below I have assigned letter *g* to the mount, make sure you assign a unassigned letter in your PC.

```
mountvol g: /s
g:
cd EFI\
```

You should see a Microsoft folder and Ubuntu folder within EFI.

> Part 2: Copy *grubx64.efi* from Ubuntu to Microsoft\Boot\ as *bootmgfw.efi*

First create a backup of *bootmgfw.efi*

```
cd Microsoft\Boot\
rename bootmgfw.efi bootmgfw_.efi
```

Now do the copy and rename.

```
copy g:\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi g:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
rename grubx64.efi bootmgfw.efi
```

> Part 3: Unmount the EFI folder

Execute the following commands one by one.

```
c:
mountvol g: /d
```

Now reboot your PC and you should see Ubuntu grub load up which should have and option *Windows UEFI loader* to boot Windows as well.

Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold in the shift key while booting the GRUB menu should load. Choose Ubuntu.

To change the boot time from 0 seconds to 10 or so once in Ubuntu run in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit these two lines to look like this:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

replace the 10's with the timeouts desired.

After this you must run this to apply changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this is helpful!